# Can I use native the Qt5 C++ library to create applications for the phone?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

Can I use native Qt5 C++ library to create for Ubuntu phone. Is there any guide or wiki for it. How can I test my app on real device(Galaxy Nexus). Where I can get recommendations for Ubuntu App Designing,  documentation of Ubuntu SDK QML components.

Comment: Here you will find everything you need: http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/

Answer (score 4):

The Ubuntu SDK is based on Qt5 respectively QtQuick 2.0 and QML. So you should be able to use all Qt5 libraries. Further information you could find on the [Ubuntu SDK](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.10/qml/mobile/overview-ubuntu-sdk.html), the [Qt5](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/index.html), the [QtQuick](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qtquick-applicationdevelopers.html) and the [QML](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-index.html) Documentation pages.

To test your application on a real device you have to wait until the release of the first version of the Ubuntu Phone OS which will be released next week ([February 21st](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/ubuntu-phone-downloads-to-be-released-next-week)). The 3rd generation Galaxy Nexus will support the Ubuntu Phone OS but there will be other devices. For further details have a look at the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch?action=show&redirect=UbuntuPhone) and the [Ubuntu Operators](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/phone/operators-and-oems) page.

Comment: I can't find a guide, how can I build Qt5 App to Ubuntu. I mean project which uses C++ code

Comment: You didn't browse the links aren't you? At the [QtQuick Manual](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qtquick-applicationdevelopers.html) there is a link to [code samples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qtquick2-qtquick-codesamples.html) and here you find examples "[Extending QML](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qtquick2-qtquick-codesamples.html)".

Comment: I followed the links. I'm asking not how to combine Qt5 code in C++ with QML! I'm asking, how can I **build** such app for Ubuntu Phone. I have Galaxy Nexus with Ubuntu Phone Developer Preview installed on it. I'm trying to write which will use libraries written in C++. I can build and test this app for Ubuntu Desktop, but I do not know how to build same application for my Galaxy Nexus with Ubuntu Phone on board.